# pandas equivalent of SQL distinct

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and I want to extract the rows that are unique in the manner of the SQL "select distinct" operation. So far whenever I look up forums on this I find comments about counting distinct (but I want the actual values) or (worse) values that are distinct in two columns just joined together as one set (using ravel). What I want is, for example for two columns, values that are distinct in pairs and the result as a dataframe.

I am considering now that the most effective method might be to write it myself - doing a stable sort on tuples and then scanning for duplicates. Any pandas expression that is no simpler than doing essentially that is not an answer to this question. I am looking for a basic or simple compound operation.

---

For those who do not know what a "distinct" in a query does ...

Starting with

```
1 2
2 3
1 2
4 5
2 3
2 1
```

we get back

```
1 2
2 3
4 5
2 1
```

Note - the question was asked should (2,1) and (1,2) be considered the same. No, as tuples are ordered. Again - refer to the behaviour of SQL for the details.

Comment: What's your RDMS? If you're using postgres - then Django has support for using `DISTINCT ON` (see notes at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) but your mileage may vary with others...

Comment: @JonClements this is a Pandas DataFrame question. It is not based on a separate relational database system. Think in terms of having a CSV file and reading this into a Pandas DataFrame and then using Pandas to determine unique rows. I could do this by uploading to a database service - but I am asking how to do this in a DataFrame using Pandas.

Comment: Please add a sample of your dataframe to the question, and a sample dataframe based on that one, containing your expected output. :)

Comment: @Bruce oh sorry... so you're basically after... `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['column1', 'column2'])` ?

Comment: @JonClements that sounds right, I will try it and get back in a minute.

Comment: @Bruce should (1, 2) and (2, 1) be considered the same?

Comment: @JonClements that's it, thanks. Trying to find that method from its function was unexpectedly difficult.

Comment: @JonClements No, tuples are ordered so (1,2) and (2,1) are not the same.

Comment: Looks like Azuuu has answered it then :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239864/discussion-between-bruce-and-jon-clements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the unique values of a given column, try [`pandas.Series.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html):

```
values = df['column_name'].unique()
```

To get unique combinations of given columns, try [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['colmun_name1', 'column_name2'])
```

Comment: Azuuu - don't mind my edit, it just improves clarity etc. :)